# XSLT moving nodes into a list

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Im new to Xslt and have the following problem

```
<root>
<parentnode>
<childnode1>value1</childnode1>
<childnode2>value2</childnode2>
<childnode3>value3</childnode3>
<childnode4>value4</childnode4>
<childnodelist>
</childnodelist>
</parentnode>
</root>
```

output I want:

If there is a value in either childnode3 or childnode4 I need to move the value into the childnodelist node and then delete the original node so it will be displayed as the following:

```
<root>
<ParentNode>
<childnode1>value1</childnode1>
<childnode2>value2</childnode1>
<childnodelist>
<Value name="childnode3">value3</Value>
<Value name="childnode4">Value4</Value>
</childnodelist>
</parentnode>
</root>
```

My current xslt has the following code but I am unsure how to test whether there is a value in the node, and if so how to create the new node. I want to try to avoid using "xsl:if" as I've read it's not best practice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="CommercialDataOutput\StructuralVariable\Spare1">

  <!--Unsure what do do here-->

<xsl:template match='childnode3|childnode4'/>
```

Comment: Do your nodes *actually* have a counting number in their name or is that just an example? (Counters in node names always make everything more difficult.)

Comment: There are no counters. The numbers are just for the purposes of the example.

Comment: Then I'd ask you to remove the counters from your sample, they don't do any good. My advice is to keep as close to your actual input as you can. (This also leads to further questions: *Which* child nodes ought to be wrapped? The last two? Those after the second one?)

Comment: Also your sample ist not well-formed XML. Please correct that, while you're at it.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank for pointing out the errors in the xml, I have changed them. I'm not going to change the numbers in the xml tags, I take your point but as there are already answers this would now confuse matters more!

Comment: Agreed. Remember it for next time, it will save brain cycles for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply need

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="parentNode[normalize-space(foo) or normalize-space(bar)]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::foo | self::bar)]"/>
    <list>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="foo | bar" mode="wrap"/>
    </list>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo | bar" mode="wrap">
  <value name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </value>
</xsl:template>
```

where `foo` and `bar` are the elements you want to check and transform if one has content.

Comment: Thanks Martin. This solution is great, however when there is no value for foo or bar an empty element is still produced. Is it possible to only create the element when it has a value, or delete it after it's created?

Comment: @RichardWatts, the `match="parentNode[normalize-space(foo) or normalize-space(bar)]"` should ensure that the whole template is only used and executed for `parentNode` elements having at least a `foo` or a `bar` element with some contents, that way the addition of the `list` element is also restricted to that case. If you don't want an empty `value name="foo"` then change `<xsl:apply-templates select="foo | bar" mode="wrap"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="foo[normalize-space()] | bar[normalize-space()]" mode="wrap"/>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it now works exactly how I need

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to override the identity template like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="childnodelist[not('' = (../childnode3|../childnode4))]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../childnode3|../childnode4"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="childnode3[. != '']" />
    <xsl:template match="childnode4[. != '']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result for your (sanitized) input sample:

```
<root>
  <parentnode>
    <childnode1>value1</childnode1>
    <childnode2>value2</childnode2>
    <childnodelist>
      <childnode3>value3</childnode3>
      <childnode4>value4</childnode4>
    </childnodelist>
  </parentnode>
</root>
```